# Display sql of executed statement Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to display sql code of the executed statement like `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table`, but it return `1` meaning the exution was successful, so how I can see the code like

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table')->queryRow();
```

This will give you an **array** containing `table name` and `the sql query for creating the table`. Eg:-

```
array
(
'Table'=>'my_table',
'Create Table'=>'Query For Creating Table'
)
```

SO you can get the desired result using

```
$result['Create Table']
```

Answer (score 2):

Better you can try http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/ which will show you the all sql queries traces.

Comment: I need this code not for debug purposes. But thanks, I think toolbur will be useful too .)